# How can I run gradle wrapper behind a firewall / using a proxy maven server?

Tags: build, wrapper, gradle

I have been trying to get Gradle working on our Continuous Integration server, which has no access to internet (external) URLs.

Currently, we get our maven-style dependencies from an internal proxy server. So I uploaded the gradle wrapper onto that server too, such that when the CI server starts up it can download the wrapper from the internal maven proxy server.

Problem solved, I thought; the build will carry on and pull down the project dependencies from the internal proxy server as well (it's set up in the build script) and should be OK now.

But in between getting the wrapper Zip file and starting the build, it's doing the following:

```
Downloading http://maven.internal.mycompany.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/gradle/gradle/1.0-milestone-3/gradle-1.0-milestone-3-bin.zip ................
Unzipping /home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-3-bin.zip to /home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists
Set executable permissions for: /home/user/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.0-milestone-3/bin/gradle
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.7.3/groovy-1.7.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.pom
etc...

*** then the actual build starts ***
Download http://maven.internal.mycompany.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
```

E.g. it's trying to pull down extra dependencies for the gradle executable from **repo1.maven.org** which fails on the continous integration server, as it has no access to this server.

In my build.gradle file I have:

```
repositories {
    mavenRepo urls: "http://maven.internal.mycompany.com:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"
}
```

and in my ./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file I have :

```
    distributionUrl=http\://maven.internal.mycompany.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/gradle/gradle/1.0-milestone-3/gradle-1.0-milestone-3-bin.zip
```

So is there another place I can specify which server the wrapper should use to get it's additional dependencies ? Or is this hard-coded into the wrapper itself ? Or I might be missing a trick here, as Google doesn't seem to show up anyone else having this issue at all !

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picked up a hint from another forum that led me to the answer - a plugin for cobertura that I was pulling down had it's own gradle build file that included the default maven repositories.

I've removed that now, and the calls to external maven have ceased.